# Oracle EBS/APPS: Null value in column DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM inside table PA_DRAFT_INVOICE_DETAILS_ALL. How to fetch lines?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, null, oracle-ebs

I have the following query:

```
select 
    ppdid.EXPENDITURE_ITEM_ID, 
    ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM,
    ppdid.BILL_AMOUNT,
    ppdid.CREATION_DATE,    
    ppeia.EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE, 
    pppa.SEGMENT1 PROJECT_NUMBER,    
    ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM,
    ppdia.RA_INVOICE_NUMBER
from
    PA.PA_DRAFT_INVOICE_DETAILS_ALL ppdid,
    PA.PA_EXPENDITURE_ITEMS_ALL ppeia,
    PA.PA_PROJECTS_ALL pppa,
    PA.PA_DRAFT_INVOICES_ALL ppdia
where ppdid.EXPENDITURE_ITEM_ID = ppeia.EXPENDITURE_ITEM_ID
and   ppdid.PROJECT_ID          = pppa.PROJECT_ID
and   ppdid.PROJECT_ID          = ppdia.PROJECT_ID
--and ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM
and   (   ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM
       or ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdid.ORIG_DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM
      )  
and   pppa.SEGMENT1 = '123456' --fictive number
and   ppdia.GL_PERIOD_NAME = '05-2020'
order by ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM;
```

The problem is the case of an invoice that was created in APR-2020 and credited in MAY-2020. The transactions in all such cases (original and credit invoice in different months, AND not reissued) will not be fetched by query, even if I take out the `pppdia.GL_PERIOD_NAME` condition.

I tried to put the `(+)` on different side of the joins, but same result.

Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Why include commented out code in your posted query? We don't know your business rules but you're supposed to. Including commented code without explaining why is just more confusing for us.

Answer (score 1):

That is because NULL does not equal anything including another NULL. This then causes your predicate

```
and
--ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM
  (
  ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM  = ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM  or ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdid.ORIG_DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM
  )
```

To **ALWAYS** return false, so your query returns 0 rows. Add an or IS Null to your list of ORs

```
and
--ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM
  (  ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM  
  or ppdia.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM = ppdid.ORIG_DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM
  or ppdid.DRAFT_INVOICE_NUM is null
  )
```